# Error from Identity Provider - OIDC Scope Error

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, linkedin-api, idp

I have set up an app in LinkedIn Developers. I want to sign in to my app using LinkedIn OIDC.

LinkedIn is the IDP (Identity Provider) in my OAuth flow.

In LinkedIn, on my app, I assigned the sign in with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect product.

When initiating my flow, however, I am getting the following scope error:

> Error from identity provider: unauthorized_scope_error Scope "r_emailaddress" is not authorized for your application

OAuth scopes on my app are `openid`, `profile` and `email`, so I would have assumed the app is authorised.

I also requested an access token for the app.

Please advise?